# Run functions that are stored in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am pushing some functions into an array but I am not sure how to run the functions as I loop through the array.

I am trying to get `red` `yellow` `green` to output to the console.

Here is a fiddle to my JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/rYNv4/

Here is the code that I have so far as well:

```
var myArr = [];

myArr.push( logItRunner('red')  );
myArr.push( logItRunner('yellow') );
myArr.push( logItRunner('green')  );
console.log(myArr);

//Function to be stored in array.  Should return the logIt function.
function logItRunner( arg ) {
    return function() {
        logIt( arg );
    };
}

//Function to log a string to the console
function logIt (color) {
    console.log(color);  
};

//Function to loop through array and fire functions within the array
function runIt () {
    for (var i = 0, len = myArr.length; i < len; i++) {
        //Fire Function within Array at position i and log the argument to the console.
        myArr[i];
    };
};

runIt();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myArr[i]` is a function reference. You call the function it refers to just like you do any other time you have a function reference, with `()`:

In your loop, change:

```
myArr[i];
```

to

```
myArr[i]();
```

Comment: Thanks!  This might seem dumb but I'm not too familiar with working with arrays which is why I was trying to push functions into them.  Is it normal for a function in an array to be logged as `[function, function, function]` to the console?  I was trying to log it as the name of the function.  Thanks again T.J!

Comment: @Mdd: Happy to help. Your functions don't have names, you're creating them using anonymous function expressions like this: `function() { logIt(arg); }`. Depending on what browser you're using, if they did have names, you might or might not see them when dumping to the console.

Answer (score 1):

See how I'm executing the **myArri;** below.

You've almost got it, you just forgot the ().

```
//Function to loop through array and fire functions within the array
function runIt () {
    for (var i = 0, len = myArr.length; i < len; i++) {
        //Fire Function within Array at position i and log the argument to the console.
        myArr[i]();
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is all about how JavaScript closures work, this usually is the way we teach JavaScript closures, so your sample is a good one, since it clarifies the concept.

This is the way I usually do the exact same thing to teach JavaScript closures, which is completely similar to yours with some little differences:

```
var myArr = [];
myArr.push('red');
myArr.push('yellow');
myArr.push('green');

var funcArr=[];
function pushIt () {
    for (var i = 0, len = myArr.length; i < len; i++) {
        var func = (function(color){
            return (function(){
                console.log(color);
            });
        })(myArr[i]);
        funcArr.push(func);
    };
};
function runIt () {
    for (var i = 0, len = funcArr.length; i < len; i++) {
        funcArr[i]();
    };
};
pushIt();
runIt();
```